# Why isnt my foreach loop working?

Tags: php, html

This is frustrating, After I feed an values from a text field in a HTML form like the below. In the PHP file below I read in these values, turn them into an array and then attempt to print out only the text fields that were filled in via a foreach loop. For some strange reason the foreach loop endsup printing all the textfields regardless if they were filled in or not. Why do I fail to print out only the filled in text fields? Where am I going wrong in my code:

Find below my HTML file:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="chk123.php">
Flights on: <br/>

Sunday =    <input  type="datetime-local" name="Days[]" value="bdaytime"> <br>
Monday =      <input  type="datetime-local" name="Days[]" value="bdaytime"> <br>
Tuesday =   <input  type="datetime-local" name="Days[]" value="bdaytime"> <br>
Wednesday = <input  type="datetime-local" name="Days[]" value="bdaytime"> <br>
Thursday =  <input  type="datetime-local" name="Days[]" value="bdaytime"> <br>
Friday =      <input  type="datetime-local" name="Days[]" value="bdaytime"> <br>
Saturday =  <input  type="datetime-local" name="Days[]" value="bdaytime"> <br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now my PHP file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{       
    $checkBox = implode(', ', $_POST['Days']);
    $checkBoxArray = explode(', ', $checkBox);

foreach ($checkBoxArray as $value)
   {
    echo "Inserting >>> ".$value. "<br />";
   }

    echo "<br />Complete";
}    
?>
```

Looking forward to your feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a correct behavior for text fields. They are always present in POST request, even with empty values (in contrast to checkboxes).
You can filter them out like this:

```
$checkBox = implode(', ', array_filter($_POST['Days']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$checkBoxArray = $_POST['Days'];

foreach ($checkBoxArray as $value)
{
     echo "Inserting >>> ".$value. "<br />";
}
```

Since it is already an array.For that you didnt need to explode and implode it even.Directly use that array `Days`